# Fuelphp redirect to file

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink, routes, fuelphp

Fuelphp redirect to file.
In fuelphp in the public folder i have a folder named files(public/files).
There i have some pdf and jpeg files i want to create a hyperlink to these files, so when i access the hiperlink it will take me to that file and view it in browser, like when you access a direct file on server in apache. 
I created the hiperlink like this: myhost/index.php/files/myfile.pdf but i don't know how to access it. Do i have to setup something in routes? Or there is another way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the hyperlink to `myhost/files/myfile.pdf` if your server can understand `public/.htaccess (mod_rewrite)`.